# Comparação de datas PHP e MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tendo problemas com um código, como sou novo na área estou desenvolvendo apenas para aprender. O que eu quero fazer:
Realizar um controle de acesso mensal do usuário, ou seja, caso não esteja paga a mensalidade ele não acessa. O meu problema é para conferir se a data de expiração do usuário é menor ou igual a CURRENT DATE. Caso a data de expiração seja igual a data atual, o valor da coluna "pago" será "0", ou seja ele não pagou. Caso contrário, "1".
Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
function isExpired()
{
    global $conn;
    global $empresa;
    $sql2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nome_fantasia = '$empresa' AND DATE(expire_date) = DATE(NOW())");
    if (mysqli_fetch_row($sql2)==1) {
        //expirou
        $confere = "UPDATE FROM clientes SET `pago` = 0 WHERE nome_fantasia = '$empresa'";
        $editar = mysqli_query($conn, $confere); //Realiza a consulta
        if ($editar == '') {
            echo 'nao deu';
        } else {
            echo 'alterou';
        }
    }
}
isExpired();
```

Não sei se ficou claro o que quero, peço desculpas. Qualquer coisa tento explicar mais.
PS: to aprendendo a mexer com funções, QUALQUER DICA ou CRITICA é SUPER BEM VINDA. 
O código não me retornar nem o

```
if ($editar == '') {
            echo 'nao deu';
        } else {
            echo 'alterou';
        }
```

obg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu UPDATE, não precisa do FROM, você pode fazer desta forma:

```
  $confere = "UPDATE clientes SET `pago` = 0 WHERE nome_fantasia = '$empresa'";
```

O retorno do mysqli_query pode ser false em caso de erro, ou true no caso de sucesso do update. Aqui tem mais explicações:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score -1):

Primeira coisa, a sua query, as datas nao tem se ser comparadas só se são iguais mas tb menor, então tem que substituir **=** com **<=**
controla se no Database os datos sao mudados ou não
E para verificar se a query foi executada tenta com esse codigo

```
if ($editar){
            echo 'nao deu';
        } else {
            echo 'alterou';
        }
```